# AjaxBehaviorEvent primefaces3.2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

My problem is that the following code returns null but if I look when debuging source then submittedValue has the correct date.

Java:

```
public void changeOneMenuP(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
      String id  = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("value");
      if(id != null) {
           listEntity = escDao.findByxxxx(id, true);
      }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="idSelect" immediate="true" style="width:120px" value="#EntityBB.idUni}" label="#{bundleComunes.unidad}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundleComunes.seleccionar}..." itemValue="" />
                                            <f:selectItems  value="#{configuracionBB.listEntity}" var="lUni" itemValue="#lUni.id}" itemLabel="#{lUni.desc}" />
                                    <p:ajax event="change" update="sisArm" listener="#{entityBB.changeOneMenuP}" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Any Idea????

Comment: the snippet of your code and your explanation is not enough to determine anything.. please give a more detailed explanation, show the entire method (declaration of event variable), add snippet of the xhtml, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better don't mix primefaces `p:ajax` with Pure JSF

try using `f:ajax`

```
<f:ajax event="change" render="sisArm" listener="#{entityBB.changeOneMenuP}" />
```

Also , you better access your `id`  like this

```
public void changeOneMenuP(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    listEntity = escDao.findByxxxx(getidUni(), true);//or just idUni
}
```